# Symlink (ln) folders doesn't work as expected

Tags: bash, symlink

I am creating a script that basically look for all the things that ends with `.symlink` and try to create a symlink to the `$HOME` directory removing the `symlink` part and adding `dot` in front of the name.

Below is the line showing how the destination is created.

```
dst="$HOME/.$(basename "${src%.*}")"
```

There are the two functions created for that

```
create_symlink () {
  local src=$1 dst=$2

  # Create the symlink
  ln -s -i "$src" "$dst"
  message "Linked $1 -------> $2" # This just use echo
}

run_symlinks() {
  message "Creating Symlinks"

  local root=$1

  # Find the files/folder and try to do the symlink
  for src in $(find -H $root -name '*.symlink')
  do
    dst="$HOME/.$(basename "${src%.*}")"

    create_symlink "$src" "$dst"
  done
}
```

**The problem**

I have a **folder** called `atom.symlink` that folder basically have some configuration for my environment with the files of Atom text editor inside. When I run `run_symlinks` function that folder **is being synced but in the wrong place.**

The output of `message "Linked $1 -------> $2"` is:

```
Linked $HOME/.dotfiles/src/symlinks/atom.symlink -------> $HOME/.atom
```

But when I look at the folder the symlink is actually to `$HOME/.atom/atom.symlink` instead of just to the `.atom` folder.

**Note:** the `$HOME/.atom` folder is not empty and I need to figure out how to make this script without worry about having an empty folder.

I tried to find the answer on Google but I could't even know how to ask this specific question about it.

Comment: This is the repo with the code: https://github.com/yordis/.dotfiles/blob/master/bin/run.sh

Comment: On another note, `basename` actually takes 2 parameters, 2nd parameter being optional one.: This second parameter is the optional suffic to be removed. So, in this case, `basename "${src%.*}"` is same as `basename "src" .symlink`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement [anishsane's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37958857/45375), which explains the problem with your approach well:

Your **desire to retain possibly preexisting (non-symlink) target folders in `$HOME` and *add* to their content** requires a **fundamentally different approach**:

The only way to solve this is to avoid symlinking the `*.symlink` *directories themselves*; instead, the *files* in these directories must be *individually symlinked* to the target folder, which is either a preexisting folder or one that must be created as a regular folder on demand.
That is the only way to guarantee that the existing content of the target folder is not (invariably) lost:

```
while IFS= read -r f; do
  # Strip $root from the file path, then remove suffix '.symlink' and add prefix '.'
  # to the path commponent(s) to get the link path.
  link="$HOME/$(sed 's#\([^/]\{1,\}\)\.symlink\(/\{0,1\}\)#.\1\2#g' <<<"${f#$root/}")"
  # Make sure that the parent path exists, creating it on demand (as *regular* folder(s)).
  mkdir -p -- "$(dirname -- "$link")"
  # Now we can create the symlink.
  echo "symlinking [$link] <- [$f]"
  # Note the need to redirect from `</dev/tty` so as not
  # to suppress the interactive prompt (`-i`).
  ln -s -i "$f" "$link" </dev/tty
done < <(find -H "$root" -type f \( -path '*.symlink' -or -path '*.symlink/*' \))
```

The approach is a follows:

- The `find` command finds only *files*, namely those *themselves* named `*.symlink`, and those inside *directories* named `*.symlink` (whatever suffix the files themselves have).
- For each file, the target symlink path is determined by removing the `$root` path prefix, and then removing suffix `.symlink` and adding prefix `.` to matching path components.
- The existence of each target symlink path's parent path is ensured with `mkdir -p`: any existing path components are retained as-is, and any non-existent ones are created as *regular* folders.
- Once the existence of the target folder for the symlink is ensured / established, the `ln` command can be invoked.

  - Note that `-i` - to present an interactive prompt asking for replacement in case the link's path already exists - requires stdin to be a *terminal* in order to kick in; thus, given that stdin is redirected to the process substitution providing the output from `find`, `</dev/tty` is needed to show the prompt.

Comment: Got it! I had more levels deeper that's why I leave the `find` I will considerate to do this if I just put it in the same level all the time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @YordisPrietoLazo: Now that the requirements have become clearer, I've completely rewritten the answer.

Comment: Oh, so OP wants that `blabla.symlink/*` should be symlinked at `$HOME/.blabla/`

Comment: @anishsane: I think he wants the _individual files_ in `blabla.symlink/*` to be _added_ to `$HOME/.blabla` (as symlinks with their original basenames), where `$HOME/.blabla` _may already exist_ (as a regular directory), in which case  _its existing content must be preserved_. (I just fixed a bug in the renaming logic.)

Answer (score 3):

From [`man ln`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/ln/):

```
   ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
   ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)
   ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
   ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...  (4th form)

   In  the 1st form, create a link to TARGET with the name LINK_NAME.  In the
   2nd form, create a link to TARGET in the current directory.   In  the  3rd
   and  4th  forms,  create  links  to each TARGET in DIRECTORY.  Create hard
   links by default, symbolic links with --symbolic.  By default, each destination
   (name  of  new link) should not already exist.  When creating hard
   links, each TARGET must exist.  Symbolic links can hold arbitrary text; if
   later  resolved,  a relative link is interpreted in relation to its parent
   directory.
```

After first iteration of your script, you have

```
$HOME/.atom/ -> $HOME/.dotfiles/src/symlinks/atom.symlink # This is the first form in above man page snippet.
```

In the second iteration, you fall in the 3rd form, because the target already existed & after symlink dereferencing, it's a directory.

So, the command run is same:

```
  ln -s -i $HOME/.dotfiles/src/symlinks/atom.symlink $HOME/atom
```

Only difference is that in the second iteration, the target is an existing directory (after dereferencing).

So you should first delete the target (`rm -f "$dst"`) & then create a symlink. Luckily, `ln` can do it by itself:

Change your code to:

```
ln -sfn "$src" "$dst" # Note that with -f & -n in place, usage of -i is moot.
```

Comment: `ln` doesn't do it. I guess there is not way to do it and I have to remove the folder?!

Comment: Not folder, just the symlink. In your case, `$dst`... btw, `ln` should do it with these options; but maybe you have a different build of `ln`. You can use `rm` or `unlink` to remove old symlink...

Comment: With those options it doesn't create the symlink. I can't remove the `.atom` folder because there is some stuff that I should't remove.

I guess I have to actually move that symlink to the files inside `atom.symlink` folder

Comment: `$HOME/.atom` is not a folder; it's just a symlink to another folder. You should be able to remove symlink, without any loss of contents of the directory...

Comment: I am trying to create a symlink to a folder that already exists and then will be a symlink. Before I run that command that `.atom` folder already exists that's what I am trying to say

Comment: Again... `$HOME/.atom` is not a folder. If you `rm $HOME/.atom`, contents of `$HOME/.dotfiles/src/symlinks/atom.symlink` folder will not be lost.

Comment: It doesn't because that symlink is not being created. The symlink is created from `$HOME/.atom/atom.symlink` to `$HOME/.dotfiles/src/symlinks/atom.symlink`

Comment: so, `$HOME/.atom` is a symlink or an actual folder? what does `ls -ld $HOME/.atom` say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115362/discussion-between-yordis-prieto-lazo-and-anishsane).